# closure compiler output on the same file not working

Tags: google-closure-compiler, google-closure, google-closure-library

I try to override my source file with compiled version at build time.

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js test.js --js_output_file test.js
```

the above command succeed but the content of test.js gets wipped out. 
If I output to a different file then it works.

What should i do to make it override the same  file with minified 
version?

Answer (score 2):

try:

```
java -jar compiler.jar --js test.js > test2.js; mv test2.js test.js
```

Comment: This works but I thought I can do it w/o mv